# How to make a text vertically alligned in html?

Tags: html

This is what I did now

```
<body background="2017-02-27 (5).png">
    <table cellspacing="1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td valign="middle" align="center">
            <h1>Click here to Get Game and See Yourself</h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
```

You can see the result here

http://romancepriorities.com/test/

The text is on top. I want the text to be on the center of the screen. So what did I do wrong?

[image]
So the whole page is a one big file with one big background and I want a big text on the center.

It doesn't work. The word Click here to get Game is still on top. It's horizontally aligned, but it's still on top.

Comment: Vertically aligned … against what?

Comment: I tried to see what's wrong with your code but every attempt was already aligning vertically any text of the table...

Comment: Vertically aligned in the whole page. Sorry. I change the code

Answer (score 0):

1) The height "line-height:150px;" and your div height has to be same in where you want to centre it.

2) "line-height:100vh;" will make the text to be at the centre of the page.

```css
h1{
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;       /* 1) The height same as your div height where you want to centre it. 2) line-height: 100vh will make it to centre of the page. */
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="center">
        <h1>Click here to Get Game and See Yourself</h1>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use position: absolute; top: 50%; without height:100%

```
<table cellspacing="1" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="center">
        <h1>Click here to Get Game and See Yourself</h1>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```